# Parameter must be an array

Tags: android, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to send `parameter` to `Facebook marketting API`

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name","My campaign");
    params.putString("objectives","LINK_CLICKS");
    params.putString("status","PAUSED");
    params.putString("special_ad_categories", "[NONE]");
```

the `API` accepting `parameters` are

special_ad_categories

```
array<enum {NONE, EMPLOYMENT, HOUSING, CREDIT, ISSUES_ELECTIONS_POLITICS}>
```

Error i am getting is

```
Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#100) The parameter special_ad_categories must be an array.}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `params.putExtra("special_ad_categories", new FacebookEnum[]{FacebookEnum.NONE});`
Where the name of the FacebookEnum class replace with the one that uses the Facebook api

Comment: I will try .. but i solved it with java business sdk